# Queries regarding Light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

[image]

1. In the given picture,why has light been depicted so ? We know that light travels and propagates in a straight line in a given medium having the same refractive index throughout.
   [image]

2. When we refer to the wavelength of light , do we refer to the wavelength of the wave-like pattern created by the oscillation of Electric field or Magnetic field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) That rough sketch represents the amplitude of the electric or magnetic field, not the path the light follows.
2.) As the image shows, both fields have the same wavelength.